# overloading operator "=" for vectors with shared ptr c++

Tags: c++, memory, methods, overriding, overloading

I'm trying to make a little game on c++ and I'm trying to overload the "=" operator. It is supposed to copy the game, and make the copy undependable. Looks like I'm doing something wrong with the memory or something like that, because when I try to print the copy it crashes. What am I doing wrong?
This is the overloading:

```
Game& Game::operator=(const Game& other){
        std::vector<Pair> new_grid;
        for(int i=0; i < other.grid_characters.size(); i++){
            Character* character = other.grid_characters[i].character->clone();
            std::shared_ptr<Character> character_shared_ptr(character);
            Pair new_element( other.grid_characters[i].grid_point, character_shared_ptr);
            new_grid.push_back(new_element);
        }
        this->height=other.height;
        this->width = other.width;
        this->grid_characters=new_grid;
        return *this;
    }
```

Overloading the "<<":

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Game& game){
        std::string grid_str_to_print;
        for(int i=0; i < game.height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < game.width; j++){
                GridPoint grid_point(i, j);
                std::shared_ptr<Character> character = getCharacterAtPoint(game, grid_point);
                if(character == nullptr){
                    grid_str_to_print += ' ';
                } else {
                    grid_str_to_print += character->getCharSymbol();
                }
            }
        }
        char* output_grid = new char[grid_str_to_print.length() +1];
        strcpy(output_grid, grid_str_to_print.c_str());
        printGameBoard(os,output_grid, output_grid + grid_str_to_print.length() ,game.width);
        delete[] output_grid;
        return os;


    }
```

And printing the board:

```
std::ostream &mtm::printGameBoard(std::ostream &os, const char *begin,
                                 const char *end, unsigned int width) {
    std::string delimiter = std::string(2 * width + 1, '*');
    const char *temp = begin;
    os << delimiter << std::endl;
    while (temp != end) {
        os << "|" << (*temp);
        ++temp;
        if ((temp - begin) % width == 0)
            os << "|" << std::endl;
    }
    os << delimiter;
    return os;
}
```

This is the pair:

```
struct Pair {
        GridPoint grid_point;
        std::shared_ptr<Character> character;
        Pair(GridPoint grid_point, std::shared_ptr<Character> character) :
                grid_point(grid_point), character(character) {}
    };
```

This is clone:

```
Character* Soldier::clone() const {
        return new Soldier(*this);
    }
```

This is the code in the main:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

#include "Exceptions.h"
#include "Game.h"

using namespace mtm;

void example1() {
    std::cout << "------example 2------" << std::endl;
    Game g1(5,10);
    g1.addCharacter(GridPoint(3,0), Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType::SOLDIER, Team::POWERLIFTERS, 20, 0, 3, 5));
    Game g2 = g1;
    std::cout << g1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << g2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nice!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    example1();

    return 0;
}
```

There is no error returned and no messages whatsoever.

Comment: Could you show the relevant parts of `Pair` and `clone`? `operator<<(std::ostream&, Game const&)` may contain required info too (or alternatively the conversion operator converting `Game` to something printable, if this is how you print `Game`. Btw: I assume there's some other place where you actually shared pointers?  Otherwise `std::unique_ptr` may be preferrable.

Comment: please show a [mre]. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @fabian I have updated it.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it looks like it does into copy constructor instead

Comment: We still need a [mre]